# Traducciónes distintas para "demit/demission" y "depose/deposition"

Tags: traducción

Tengo un documento en inglés, el "Libro de orden de la iglesia", que ha sido traducido al español. Es necesario distinguir entre "demission" de un ministro y "deposition" de un ministro ("demission" es la renuncia del oficio, "deposition" es el traslado forzoso del oficio). El traductor usó el verbo "destituir" para ambas palabras en muchos casos, pero en algunos casos tradujo "demission" como "demisión." ¿Es aceptable usar "dimitir" y "dimisión" para "to demit" y "demission", y "destituir" y "destitución" para "to depose" y "deposition"? ¿Hay palabras que son mejores que éstas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece lo más adecuado y del diccionario de la RAE tenemos:

**[dimitir](http://dle.rae.es/dimitir).** (Del lat. *dimittĕre*).

1. *tr.* Renunciar, hacer dejación de algo, como un empleo, una comisión, etc. *U. m. c. intr.*

Por el contrario:

**[destituir](http://dle.rae.es/destituir).** (Del lat. *destituĕre*).

1. *tr.* Separar a alguien del cargo que ejerce.
2. *tr. p. us.* Privar a alguien de algo.

Claramente las definiciones *oficiales* están de acuerdo con este uso.